# spring boot rest api call

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, resttemplate

IRST_NUMBER = int(input('Enter first Number: '))

Comment: getting ERROR-->     Resolved [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not 
                                                      absolute]

Comment: Please, edit you message and paste error in the Question

Answer (score 1):

Looks error at

> //localhost:9090/TicketingSystem/caselogcontroller/saveCaseLog

Provide absolute URI as follows

> http://localhost:9090/TicketingSystem/caselogcontroller/saveCaseLog